# Cross-database subquery on using database name stored in record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is the script structure below possible?

```
Select 
    *, 
   (Select Count(*) 
    from [A.DatabaseName].dbo.TableA 
    where SomeID = A.SomeID) As Total 
From
    [Database1].dbo.Table1 A
```

The subquery above is dependent on the database name from `[Database1]`.

Is this doable? If yes, how can this be implemented?

Comment: The script above will obviously throw an Invalid Object Name error message when ran, like `Invalid object name A.DatabaseName.dbo.TableA`

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic SQL for that.

Comment: Is the database in the same server?

Comment: @DineshDB yes it is. I will be using the select query in a stored procedure

Comment: @onhax, How did you get `[Database1]` value?

Comment: @DineshDB It's a fixed database name, more like a master database for the rest of the database in the server. It is where i will put the stored proc

Comment: @onhax, The Query will run on the database, right?

Comment: >>> [A.DatabaseName]<<< should be just DatabaseName

Comment: @sepupic - no - OP has stored the database name in the record and wants to use it in a sub-query.

Comment: As per @DaleK, that is what I'm exactly trying to do

Comment: @onhax so you need [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @DineshDB it won't since `A.DatabaseName` is treated by mssql engine as an object and not a database name

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, i'll look into your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Dynamic Query** will help you.

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(100),@SQLQuery VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @DBName = A.DatabaseName FROM [Database1].dbo.Table1

SELECT @SQLQuery = 'Select 
    *, 
   (Select Count(*) 
    from '+@DBName+'.dbo.TableA 
    where SomeID = A.SomeID) As Total 
From
    [Database1].dbo.Table1 A'

EXEC (@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: Neat and effective. Produces exactly what i wanted to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

---> Edit

I think i understand the weird thing you are tying to do.

You store some database name into a table and the want to call if from a subquery.

You have to try something like this :

```
CREATE DATABASE test

use test

CREATE TABLE client
(
ID IDENTITY(1,1),
[name] varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO client
([name])
VALUES
('Jean'), ('Paul'), ('Mark'), ('Pierre');


CREATE TABLE allTable
(
NomSchema VARCHAR(200),
NomTable VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO allTable
VALUES 
(
'TEST','client'
)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ResultA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ResultA
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200);
SELECT TOP(1) * INTO #resultA FROM allTable
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + (SELECT quotename(#resultA.NomSchema) + '.dbo.' + quotename(#resultA.NomTable)  FROM #resultA)
SELECT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
DROP TABLE #resultA
COMMIT
GO

-- DROP DATABASE TEST
```

Comment: The OP is trying to query a database based on a database name stored in the base record, thats why they wrote A.DatabaseName.

Comment: I'm afraid this wouldn't meet the requirements since the database that will be used by the subquery to select from heavily depends on [Database1].dbo.Table1 (from one of it's columns `DatabaseName`)